# Best/safest way to upgrade Elastic search on mac

Tags: elasticsearch, homebrew

I have an older version of Elasticsearch and I need to move to 2.3. What is the best/safest way to do so on my mac?

In the [elastic](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/rolling-upgrades.html#upgrade-node) site it instructs to manually download the new installation and then copy the config file to the new installation. Before that one should stop all the shards, etc..

My question is can i use brew to update elasticsearch? What will happen if i do `brew install elasticsearch` Will it override the previous installation?
I m really concerned not to mess up my system, that s why i need an advice. 
Thnx

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `brew` installs in separate directory (`/usr/local/Cellar/`) and if you have installed yor previous version manually (wothout brew) after `brew install elasticsearch` you will get a new copy of `elasticsearch` on your MAC.

Wich one of them will be used by your application, depends on your configuration.

Comment: Actually, I also used brew to install the previous version. So you re right I already have my 1.4. version in "/usr/local/Cellar/".
If i run again "brew install elasticsearch" do you think it will overwrite the previous version? Maybe I need first manually delete my previous version from the directory?

Comment: if it is your local environment, i think you can easily type `brew update` and `brew upgrade`.
But make sure that your project's libraries support a new version of `elasticsearch` beacuse my symfony2 project - don't.